# How do I hash a column of a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hash, sql-server-2014

I receive raw data files from external sources and need to provide analysis on them.  I load the files into a table & set the fields as varchars, then run a complex SQL script that does some automated analysis. One issue I've been trying to resolve is: *How to tell if a column of data is duplicated with 1 or more other columns in that same table?*

My goal is to have, for every column, a hash, checksum, or something similar that looks at a column's values in every row *in the order they come in*.  I have dynamic SQL that loops through every field (different tables will have a variable number of columns) based on the fields listed in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, so no concerns on how to accomplish that part.

I've been researching this all day but can't seem to find any sensible way to hash every row of a field.  Google & StackOverflow searches return how to do various things to rows of data, but I couldn't find much on how to do the same thing vertically on a field.

So, I considered 2 possibilities & hit 2 roadblocks:

1. *HASHBYTES* - Use 'FOR XML PATH' (or similar) to grab every row & use a delimiter between each row, then use HASHBYTES to hash the long string.  Unfortunately, this won't work for me since I'm running **SQL Server 2014**, and HASHBYTES is limited to an input of 8000 characters.  (I can also imagine performance would be abysmal on tables with millions of rows, looped for 200+ columns).
2. *CHECKSUM + CHECKSUM_AGG* - Get the CHECKSUM of each value, turning it into an integer, then use CHECKSUM_AGG on the results (since CHECKSUM_AGG needs integers). This looks promising, but the order of the data is not considered, returning the same value on different rows.  Plus the risk of collisions is higher.

The second looked promising but doesn't work as I had hoped...

```
declare @t1 table
    (col_1 varchar(5)
    , col_2 varchar(5)
    , col_3 varchar(5));

insert into @t1
values ('ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC')
    , ('ABC', 'ABC', 'BCD')
    , ('BCD', 'BCD', NULL)
    , (NULL, NULL, 'ABC');

select * from @t1; 

select cs_1 = CHECKSUM(col_1)
    , cs_2 = CHECKSUM(col_2)
    , cs_3 = CHECKSUM(col_3)
from @t1;

select csa_1 = CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM([col_1]))
    , csa_2 = CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM([col_2]))
    , csa_3 = CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM([col_3]))
from @t1;
```

In the last result set, all 3 columns bring back the same value: 2147449198.

**Desired results:** My goal is to have some code where csa_1 and csa_2 bring back the same value, while csa_3 brings back a different value, indicating that it's its own unique set.

Comment: the CHECKSUM and BINARY_CHECKSUM functions are very poor hash functions; you'd be better off using hashbytes(MD5)

Comment: @MitchWheat this is very informative for me as I'm using the same functions. What makes them very poor? and why should one avoid it? Thanks a lot

Comment: search for "sql server CHECKSUM  clash"

Comment: @MitchWheat - As I mentioned above, I can't use HASHBYTES(whatever, including 'MD5') because SQL 2014 HASHBYTES is limited to 8000 characters input.  I also was concerned about CHECKSUM collisions.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94520/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-values-of-whole-tables-between-many-databases

Comment: @MitchWheat - So that link suggests breaking apart every incoming step into 8000 characters, then creating a hash of the hashes.  But say the table contains a varchar(1000) comment field.  I'd have to parse out each 8000 characters to send to HASHBYTES, then stitch those hashes of hashes together, repeating the process should that 1st hash become > 8000 characters? (Hash of a hash of a hash, ad infinitum?)

Comment: As a hash function projects an indefinite key space on a definite hash space of hash values of a constant (relatively small) length, my understanding is that repeating to hash chunks and hash hashes will eventually end in a series of hashes the defined hash size of the hashing algorithm. You can stop then. So unless you're choosing a hash algorithm that produces 8000 character wide hash values you should be fine.

Comment: @MitchWheat Everyone should be aware that all of the HASHBYTES algorithms except for SHA2_256 and SHA2_512 are deprecated, and should not be used in new implementations.

Comment: This problem is not a good fit for a relational database. Basically, this treats each column as an individual ordered set. What is the cardinality of each set? Is it the number of rows in the table? Also, how should NULL be treated with respect to set comparison?

Comment: Given your root issue is **How to tell if a column of data is duplicated with 1 or more other columns in that same table?** do you need  a hash?  Presumably you only care if the column has the same values as another column for the same rows; since otherwise the row data is different.  For that you could just do: `select top 1 1 from myData a left outer join myData b on b.id = a.id and a.column1 = b.column2 having count(a.id) = count(b.id) `

Comment: @JohnLBevan The OP also needs to know if the entire set is the same, not just which rows are the same. See my solution below for an individual column.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA That should be what mine gives: all the same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6cf94/1, not all the same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6cf94/2

Comment: @Pittsburgh DBA: Yes, I know that. MD5 is way faster than SHA2_256, deprecated or not. If speed is a concern and you don't want as many clashes as checksum() then I might use it

Comment: @JohnLBevan Nice. Put it in an answer next time :-)

Comment: @JohnLBevan - Thanks for the tip! I'm starting to believe that my only option is dynamic SQL that loops & compares every column against every other column (e.g. 200 ^ 2 columns = 40,000 queries, which could be 5 million rows per query). UGH!  The goal of using a hash was to do an analysis of a column, get a hash, then say "which fields have the same hash"?

Comment: @PittsburghDBA - Just wondering if there was any possibility of creating a columnstore index and somehow comparing that index data on each field?  I'll admit to not being too familiar with columnstore indexes, but I see that (clustered? nonclustered?) could potentially tell me what I'm looking for...  (I could always "select * into #temp" and create a columnstore...)

Comment: Ah makes sense / I get it now.  There's a simpler answer too; see my posted answer; I think that'll be the easiest & most efficient option.

Comment: The columnstore index wouldn't really help this use case, because the string compression would just get into your way. Its best use cases are for aggregation rather than these types of operations.

Comment: I have another idea, equally interesting. How are you ingesting this data?

Comment: @PittsburghDBA - I'm basically taking raw data files, using Pentaho to load each file with each column as varchar(255), and naming the columns as per the data dictionary or header row 1. (I use varchars because I want to see the way data comes in, including preceding 0s, dates in the incoming format, overpunch, etc.)  So, there's a variable number of columns, with variable names.  In the above, I used "col_1", "col_2" out of simplicity...

Comment: If you're pulling the data through an ETL tool like that, you could always funnel your set through a custom transformation that basically keeps hashing the previous row's hash result with its current data value. When you reach the end of your stream, you have a hash that can only be arrived at by sequential computation, so it represents the elements of the set as well as their order. Make sure to use a proper cryptographic hash for this, such as SHA 256.

Answer (score 1):

**NEW SOLUTION**

EDIT: Based on some new information, namely that there may be more than 200 columns, my suggestion is to compute hashes for each column, but perform it in the ETL tool.

Essentially, feed your data buffer through a transformation that computes a cryptographic hash of the previously-computed hash concatenated with the current column value. When you reach the end of the stream, you will have serially-generated hash values for each column, that are a proxy for the content and order of each set.

Then, you can compare each to all of the others almost instantly, as opposed to running 20,000 table scans.

**OLD SOLUTION**

Try this. Basically, you'll need a query like this to analyze each column against the others. There is not really a feasible hash-based solution. Just compare each set by its insertion order (some sort of row sequence number). Either generate this number during ingestion, or project it during retrieval, if you have a computationally-feasible means of doing so.

NOTE: I took liberties with the NULL here, comparing it as an empty string.

```
declare @t1 table
    (
    rownum int identity(1,1)
    , col_1 varchar(5)
    , col_2 varchar(5)
    , col_3 varchar(5));

insert into @t1
values ('ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC')
    , ('ABC', 'ABC', 'BCD')
    , ('BCD', 'BCD', NULL)
    , (NULL, NULL, 'ABC');


with col_1_sets as
(
select
    t1.rownum as col_1_rownum
    , CASE WHEN t2.rownum IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS col_2_miss
    , CASE WHEN t3.rownum IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS col_3_miss
from
    @t1 as t1
    left join @t1 as t2 on
        t1.rownum = t2.rownum
        AND isnull(t1.col_1, '') = isnull(t2.col_2, '')
    left join @t1 as t3 on
        t1.rownum = t3.rownum
        AND isnull(t1.col_1, '') = isnull(t2.col_3, '')
),
col_1_misses as
(
select
    SUM(col_2_miss) as col_2_misses
    , SUM(col_3_miss) as col_3_misses
from
    col_1_sets
)
select
    'col_1' as column_name
    , CASE WHEN col_2_misses = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_col_2_match
    , CASE WHEN col_3_misses = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_col_3_match
from
    col_1_misses
```

Results:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+
| column_name | is_col_2_match | is_col_3_match |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+
| col_1       |              1 |              0 |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: With this solution, I'd have to outer join col_1 with every other column (which could be col_200 or higher). Since dynamic SQL would be required anyway & given the variable number of columns, wouldn't it be easier if I just did a derived table containing a bunch of "SELECT col_compare = 'col_1', CASE WHEN isnull(col_1,'') = isnull(col_2,'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CASE WHEN isnull(col_1,'') = isnull(col_3,'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, ....." in a derived table, run for each column vs. others, then group by col_compare and grab the MIN value for each column? Wouldn't that be faster?

Comment: Since you have so many columns, compute the hash value serially in your ETL tool, Pentaho. I made a similar comment on your original post. Then, the number of computations will be trival in your large population of columns. I'm updating my answer. Can you edit your question to reflect that there will be a high number of columns (~200)?

Answer (score 1):

You could compare every column combo in this way, rather than using hashes:

```
select case when count(case when column1 = column2 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column1EqualsColumn2
, case when count(case when column1 = column3 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column1EqualsColumn3
, case when count(case when column1 = column4 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column1EqualsColumn4
, case when count(case when column1 = column5 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column1EqualsColumn5
, case when count(case when column2 = column3 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column2EqualsColumn3
, case when count(case when column2 = column4 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column2EqualsColumn4
, case when count(case when column2 = column5 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column2EqualsColumn5
, case when count(case when column3 = column4 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column3EqualsColumn4
, case when count(case when column3 = column5 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column3EqualsColumn5
, case when count(case when column4 = column5 then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end Column4EqualsColumn5
from myData a
```

Here's the setup code:

```
create table myData
(
  id integer not null identity(1,1)
  , column1 nvarchar (32)
  , column2 nvarchar (32)
  , column3 nvarchar (32)
  , column4 nvarchar (32)
  , column5 nvarchar (32)
)

insert myData (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) 
values ('hello', 'hello', 'no', 'match', 'match')
,('world', 'world', 'world', 'world', 'world')
,('repeat', 'repeat', 'repeat', 'repeat', 'repeat')
,('me', 'me', 'me', 'me', 'me')
```

And here's the obligatory [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e9c5/3).

Also, to save you having to write this here's some code to generate the above.  This version will also include logic to handle scenarios where both columns' values are null:

```
declare @tableName sysname = 'myData'
, @sql nvarchar(max) 
;with cte as (
    select name, row_number() over (order by column_id) r
    from sys.columns 
    where object_id = object_id(@tableName, 'U') --filter on our table
    and name not in ('id') --only process for the columns we're interested in
)
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + char(10) + ', ', 'select') + ' case when count(case when ' + quotename(a.name) + ' = ' + quotename(b.name) + ' or (' + quotename(a.name) + ' is null and ' + quotename(b.name) + ' is null) then 1 else null end) = count(1) then 1 else 0 end ' + quotename(a.name + '_' + b.name)
from cte a
inner join cte b
on b.r > a.r
order by a.r, b.r

set @sql = @sql  + char(10) + 'from ' + quotename(@tableName)
print @sql
```

NB: That's not to say you should run it as dynamic SQL; rather you can use this to generate your code (unless you need to support the scenario where the number or name of columns may vary at runtime, in which case you'd obviously want the dynamic option).